# Audio processing in kivy

Tags: python, audio, kivy, convolution

I would like to do some basic audio-signalprocessing in kivy. For example, I would like to convolve a .wav file with an impulse response. I use SoundLoader.load('file.wav') to load the audio files.

My question is: is it possible to convert an audio object into a list, so I can access each sample? Or does the SoundLoader class offer any possibilities of convolution, or any other audio processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used kivy's SoundLoader yet, but a quick glance at the API tells me, it is not suggested for audio processing but for playing audio in kivy: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html

Instead you should probably take a closer look at the wave module of the standard lib, which I haven't used either but which seems to provide some basic audio processing like accessing samples and so on: https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

If it doesn't fit your needs, here are a lot of third party modules for audio concerns:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the wave module. Works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a project under development that you may want to take a look at. I have only used it briefly, as I had a hard time setting it up. I could run most of the demos provided with it, but there were other demos involving pure data that I couldn't. The problem was I couldn't find a file called pylibpd anywhere online!(I don't think I'm alone in that, even the creator didn't know where I could get it), however, you might have more luck than I did. It just occurred to me, that the creator himself, must surely have the file, as it was required to run some demos... and will hopefully provide a mirror or something. Anyway, what I did look at seemed pretty cool. There was various types of wave generation with the ability to manipulate them, from what I remember. https://github.com/kivy/audiostream

Comment: Ok I think they are processing the audio data from the microphone. I was rather looking for a way to process existing wav files. But thanks for the hint anyway, this project looks pretty interesting

Comment: The description they give of the project says that alright, but you can also generate audio signals not originating from the microphone or use your own samples and manipulate those, though I'm not sure to what extent.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy is not really obviously designed for Audio or Signal Processing and doesn't need to be thats why you have python and its massive collections of libraries, you can use 'numpy', 'scipy', 'librosa', and so on....
with numpy you could get an array of the signal

Comment: You might want to put this as a comment